# combine multiple queries into single query

Tags: oracle11g

I have 2 queries and calling a function 2 times I need call the function one time only based on `msg_sys_no` count and  `msg_trans_type`.
please find the queries mentioned below and provide me the solution for merging into single.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b1.msg_sys_no) INTO A
    FROM tra_message b1
    WHERE TO_CHAR(b1.msg_when_created,'YYYY-MM-DD') = in_start_date
    AND b1.msg_service_provider                   = in_svc_provider
    AND b1.msg_trans_type = 'TRADE1'
    AND get_transaction_status_func(b1.msg_sys_no, b1.msg_trans_type) = 'S';

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b1.msg_sys_no) INTO B
    FROM tra_message b1
    WHERE TO_CHAR(b1.msg_when_created,'YYYY-MM-DD') = in_start_date
    AND b1.msg_service_provider                   = in_svc_provider
    AND b1.msg_trans_type = 'TRADE2'
    AND get_transaction_status_func(b1.msg_sys_no, b1.msg_trans_type) = 'S';
```

Comment: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b1.msg_sys_no)  TRADE1,  
        COUNT(DISTINCT b1.msg_sys_no)  TRADE2
         
 INTO A,B
    FROM tra_message b1
    WHERE TO_CHAR(b1.msg_when_created,'YYYY-MM-DD') = in_start_date
    AND b1.msg_service_provider                   = in_svc_provider
    AND b1.msg_trans_type  IN ('TRADE1','TRADE2')
    AND get_transaction_status_func(b1.msg_sys_no, b1.msg_trans_type) = 'S';

Comment: but it is giving wrong count can you please provide me the details where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
WITH tra_data
     AS (SELECT *
           FROM tra_message
          WHERE TO_CHAR (msg_when_created, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = in_start_date
                AND msg_service_provider = in_svc_provider
                AND get_transaction_status_func (msg_sys_no, msg_trans_type) =
                       'S')
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM tra_data
 WHERE msg_trans_type = 'TRADE1'
UNION
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM tra_data
 WHERE msg_trans_type = 'TRADE2'
```

Comment: how we need to count with msg_sys_no and store the data into A,B out parameters..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your AND b1.msg_trans_type IN ('TRADE1','TRADE2') condition.

Try something like this:

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT a) TRADE1,
       COUNT(DISTINCT b) TRADE2
into A,B
from (
select case when b1.msg_trans_type = 'TRADE1'
            then b1.msg_sys_no
            else null end as a,
       case when b1.msg_trans_type = 'TRADE2'
            then b1.msg_sys_no
            else null end as b
FROM tra_message b1 
WHERE TO_CHAR(b1.msg_when_created,'YYYY-MM-DD') = in_start_date
AND b1.msg_service_provider = in_svc_provider
AND b1.msg_trans_type IN ('TRADE1','TRADE2')
AND get_transaction_status_func(b1.msg_sys_no, b1.msg_trans_type) = 'S'
);
```

Comment: hi thanks for your explanation but where we need to provide the b1.msg_sys_no in this code..please clarify...and also case when b1.msg_trans_type = 'TRADE1'
            then b1.msg_trans_type what value comes here...please explain

Comment: The problem with your IN clause is that you apply both count(distinct) to every record that matches either TRADE1 or TRADE2 value. So I think that you get the same value in both your counts. The purpose of my case commands is to distinguish which record satisfies the first condition, and which other satisfies the second one. So, the "a" column exposes the value that you wish to count only for the TRADE1; the same technique for TRADE2. Finally you can count both the distinct values correctly. I have updated my SQL statement to get the MSG_SYS_NO count that you need...